# Run sql query through SQL agent job across all Databases

Tags: sql-server, ssms, amazon-rds

I am trying to run the following query across all databases in one instance through SQL agent job(except master db), which is basically used for index optimization

I have created the agent job but runs through only one database. Help is appreciated. I have attached Agent job, how I have created[image]

```
USE [DBNAME]

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Objectid INT, @Indexid INT,
        @schemaname VARCHAR(100), @tablename VARCHAR(300),
        @ixname VARCHAR(500),
        @avg_fragment float, @command VARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE AWS_Cusrsor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        A.object_id, A.index_id,
        QUOTENAME(SS.NAME) AS schemaname,
        QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(B.object_id, B.database_id)) AS tablename,
        QUOTENAME(A.name) AS ixname,
        B.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS avg_fragment 
    FROM 
        sys.indexes A 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'LIMITED') AS B ON A.object_id = B.object_id 
                                                                                  AND A.index_id = B.index_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.OBJECTS OS ON A.object_id = OS.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.schemas SS ON OS.schema_id = SS.schema_id
    WHERE 
        B.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30  
        AND A.index_id > 0 
        AND A.IS_DISABLED <> 1
    ORDER BY 
        tablename,ixname

OPEN AWS_Cusrsor

FETCH NEXT FROM AWS_Cusrsor INTO @Objectid, @Indexid, @schemaname, @tablename, @ixname, @avg_fragment

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @avg_fragment >= 30.0
    BEGIN
        SET @command = N'ALTER INDEX '+@ixname+N' ON '+@schemaname+N'.'+ @tablename+N' REBUILD '+N' WITH (ONLINE = ON)';
        SET @command = N'ALTER INDEX '+@ixname+N' ON '+@schemaname+N'.'+ @tablename+N' REORGANIZE';
    END

    EXEC(@command)

    FETCH NEXT FROM AWS_Cusrsor INTO @Objectid, @Indexid, @schemaname, @tablename, @ixname, @avg_fragment
END

CLOSE AWS_Cusrsor
DEALLOCATE AWS_Cusrsor
```

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, consider this T-SQL based [SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Check out sp_msforeachdb https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/&ved=2ahUKEwjPmenFwrj8AhV_jokEHQdrDdIQFnoECBsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0vfEGI65mNAWYQYQ65GOZa

Comment: I see that Dan has linked to Ola's utility - which is a good option if you can use it.  If you cannot use it and must create something yourself, then you really need to reconsider how you are approaching the problem.  Don't embed your code in the agent - create a stored procedure that does the work and call that from the agent job.  For something like this - create 2 procedures - the first one uses a cursor over the list of databases and calls the second procedure, which then performs the index maintenance as desired.

Comment: @PatrickHurst that undocumented procedure has some known issues, primarily it will sometimes just skip databases. https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb