# Get database name dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the database name dynamically but, showing some errors.

What I have tried:

```sql
Declare @dbname varchar(40) = (select name from sys.databases where name like '%worksdw2019')

select db_name() as [Database], *  
from @dbname.dbo.DimCustomer with (readuncommitted)
```

How end result should look like

```
select db_name() as [Database], * 
from AdventureWorksdw2019.dbo.dimcustomer
```

These are the errors I am getting:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: You should just be able to use:  SELECT DB_NAME()  (if MSSQL).  It will give you the DB you are currently in/connected to.

Comment: @Brad But I am trying to get 3 part name to execute table

Comment: Remove ```with (readuncommitted)```

Comment: T-SQL and SSMS are used by several products, including (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure Synapse and Azure SQL Edge; what product are you using? I've removed the SSMS tag, as it won't be relevant here,

Comment: I am using ssms

Comment: As I stated, SSMS isn't relevant to the problem, @SQL2023 , it's just an IDE-like application. What (R)DBMS product are you using?"

Comment: As for the problem, you can't take a variable and use it to replace an object's name, which needs to be a literal. T-SQL is a compiled language and doesn't support variable replacement like a scripting language does. *Why* do you need to do this? Such requirements are often indicators or an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info); normally a design flaw if I am honest.

Comment: It looks like you are, in fact, aware that variables can't be used to replace object names, as you use dynamic SQL in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75203693/2029983), *and* the [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75049701/2029983). Why have you gone backwards here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parameterize database names, so you'll need dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @context nvarchar(1000);

SELECT @context = QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.sp_executesql'
  from sys.databases 
  where name like N'%worksdw2019';
  -- what if there is more than one?

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select db_name() as [Database], *
  from dbo.DimCustomer;';

EXECUTE @context @sql;
```

Uh, `with (readuncommitted)` -> why? [sqlblog.org/nolock](https://sqlblog.org/nolock)

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid SQL written.

You cannot write use a variable like that in SQL Server. If the database name is going to be variable as seen in your example, you will need to execute dynamic SQL using the `EXEC` command such as this example below:

```
Declare @dbname varchar(40) = (select name from sys.databases where name like '%HelloWorld')

EXEC('select db_name() as [Database], *  from ' + @dbname + '.dbo.DimCustomer with (readuncommitted);')

-- you may additionally need to escape your database name
-- if you are using special characters in your name
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.